# NGINX serving http files while behind Application AWS Load Balancer with SSL, should be https

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services

I'm completely new to this so please go easy on me. I have a site that when it's accessed through the browser, it's on https. In my admin area I have a wysiwyg (TinyMCE) and am using the MoxieManager plugin. When I select an image, it's coming over as http://mydomain(dot)com/image.jpg when it should be a relative path.

In AWS you can see that in the Application load balancer settings, I have HTTP:80 redirecting to HTTPS: 443.

[image: image of load balancer setup]

For my NGINX setup, I have the following:

```
fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=phpcache:100m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    server_name mydomain.com;

    root /home/forge/mydomain.com/public;

    expires $expires; 

    # exposure of server name ex. nginx instead of nginx/1.13.3 
    server_tokens off;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!3DES';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"; 
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    add_header Referrer-Policy "origin";

    client_max_body_size 200M;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/mydomain.com/server/*;

    # Get users true ip address
    set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/16;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

    location / {   
        # exposure of server name ex. nginx instead of nginx/1.13.3 
        server_tokens off;

        # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {

        fastcgi_cache phpcache; # The name of the cache key-zone to use
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 30m; # What to cache: 'Code 200' responses, for half an hour
        fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD; # What to cache: only GET and HEAD requests (not POST)
        add_header X-Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status; # Add header so we can see if the cache hits or misses

        # try_files $uri 404;
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;

    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    # Enable gzip compression.
    # Default: off
    gzip on;

    # Compression level (1-9).
    # 5 is a perfect compromise between size and CPU usage, offering about
    # 75% reduction for most ASCII files (almost identical to level 9).
    # Default: 1
    gzip_comp_level    5;

    # Don't compress anything that's already small and unlikely to shrink much
    # if at all (the default is 20 bytes, which is bad as that usually leads to
    # larger files after gzipping).
    # Default: 20
    gzip_min_length    256;

    # Compress data even for clients that are connecting to us via proxies,
    # identified by the "Via" header (required for CloudFront).
    # Default: off
    gzip_proxied       any;

    # Tell proxies to cache both the gzipped and regular version of a resource
    # whenever the client's Accept-Encoding capabilities header varies;
    # Avoids the issue where a non-gzip capable client (which is extremely rare
    # today) would display gibberish if their proxy gave them the gzipped version.
    # Default: off
    gzip_vary          on;

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types.
    # text/html is always compressed by gzip module.
    # Default: text/html
    gzip_types
        application/atom+xml
        application/javascript
        application/json
        application/ld+json
        application/manifest+json
        application/rss+xml
        application/vnd.geo+json
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/xml
        font/opentype
        image/bmp
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon
        text/cache-manifest
        text/css
        text/plain
        text/vcard
        text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
        text/vtt
        text/x-component
        text/x-cross-domain-policy;
}
```

In the moxiemanager config, urls are set to be relative with no protocol or domain. However, when I select an image in Moxiemanager, I get the full url, protocall, domain and path.

In the browser console, it clearly states that the MoxieManager images are loading over http and not https. See below:

[image: image of google chrome console]

My thinking is that the issue is with my NGINX setup. The reason I think this is because I have a second site that uses the exact same code and is also https but SSL is setup through Laravel Forge, it doesn't use a load balancer. When I select an image in Moxiemanager on the 2nd site, it's relative, everything works as it's suppose to. So I don't think the Moxiemanager config is wrong and I've also verified that with their support team.

Does anyone know if I'm on the right track or see an obvious solution? For at least 6 months I've scoured the internet and tried tons of different NGINX configurations with no luck. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why are you focusing on nginx? It does not create these links. Those come from your web application.

Comment: In addition, your `server` block appears to be incomplete. Please post the rest of it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, thanks, I don't know for sure, it's just what I've narrowed it down to. I have 2 sites using literally the exact same code. The only difference between the two are one is using a load balancer and the other is not. The one not using the load balancer gives me relative urls just like it's suppose to. The site with the load balancer, doesn't give me relative urls when selecting an image from MoxieManager. That is why I'm looking at nginx, what else would I look at...as I said, the code for both sites is exactly the same. So, how could it be the application?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like the application is misbehaving. It's probably going nuts because some server variable isn't set in PHP, like HTTPS or X-Forwarded-Proto, when you're behind the load balancer. You can try setting those, though no guarantees.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, isn't that what I'm doing with this, setting the header to https? if $http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") { return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; }

Comment: I also tried adding proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https; to /location, but that doesn't help either. I'm really stuck!